# Can you ever use the passato prossimo to describe atmospheric conditions?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

One of the major uses of the *imperfetto* is to describe the weather.

> *Il sole splendeva mentre camminavo.*

Can you ever use the *passato prossimo* toward the same end?

For example could you say, "ieri ha fatto bel tempo"?

Comment: You picked one of the verbs that have no _participio passato_ so that you cannot actually turn the sentence in the _passato prossimo_! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We prefer the use of *imperfetto* because it describes an event that has lasted for a while, like could be the wheather.

You can use *passato prossimo* describing something that has ended, like rain or snow for example:
- *Ieri ha piovuto.*
- *Ieri ha nevicato.*

"*Ieri ha fatto bel tempo*" sounds a bit weird.

Comment: Purists would say *ieri nevicò*.

Comment: Unfortunately *passato remoto* is dying nowadays.

Comment: _Ieri ha fatto bel tempo_ does not sound weird (http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2011/10/04/a-settembre-non-ha-fatto-bel-tempo/161792/) and the _passato remoto_ is not dying (http://www.corriere.it/politica/14_dicembre_16/prodi-disse-premier-renzi-non-voglio-piu-essere-bruciato-efaaf76e-84e9-11e4-bef0-810da32228c1.shtml).

Comment: In the common language is dying, I rarely hear it and use it in real life when talking with people.

Comment: actually, *"ieri la giornata è stata serena, senza una nuvola"* does not disturb me at all.

Comment: In the Southern half of the country the _passato remoto_ is used a lot in speech. In both halves of the country it is the normal tense used in novels, stories etc. What has long declined is the differentiated usage of _passato prossimo_ and _passato remoto_ (basically because the distinction is very nuanced in most cases).

Comment: Should not it be 'Ieri È piovuto'?

Comment: As @MauroVanetti said in his answer, you can use both "avere" and "essere"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, and the weather is no special case as far as verb tenses are concerned. The choice between *imperfetto*, *passato remoto* and *passato prossimo* is made according to the usual grammar rules.

> Piovve così tanto che i fiumi esondarono.
>
> Pioveva quando ci siamo baciati la prima volta.
>
> La sposa è preoccupatissima perché ha piovuto ininterrottamente per una settimana.

As with sentences unrelated to weather, in the South the *passato remoto* is used more often while in the North the *passato prossimo* tends to cannibalise sentences that a balanced usage of all tenses would render as *passato remoto*.

The problem with your sentence is that *splenduto* is not commonly used (read [Crusca's opinion](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verbi-difficili)), *splendere* is one of the verbs that lack the *participio passato* therefore you cannot simply change the tense to *passato prossimo* without rewording the sentence in some way.

BTW, [according to the Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verbo-piovere-vuole-lausiliare) you can use both *essere* or *avere* with *piovere* and similar verbs:

> È piovuto, è nevicato, è grandinato. Ha piovuto, ha nevicato, ha grandinato.

Some sources hold the opposing view that only *è piovuto* etc. are OK, but in the everyday language both forms can be heard (perhaps *ha piovuto* is even a little more common).